# Are there any official technical specs for the Eastern Alliance destroyer?

Tags: spaceship, battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-1978

In the original *Battlestar Galactica* series, they come across the destroyer for the Eastern Alliance. Are there any official technical specs for the destroyer at all? I know they mention star speed, however no explanation I have seen mentions how fast that is. Maybe light speed? I read that they had a crew of six or seven, meaning they are on watch all the time, which makes no sense at all to me.

Answer (score 1):

I never had the impression that it could go that fast as in light speed. The term "star speed" may be used as to indicate a sub light speed which is what I gathed where their level of technology is at possibly. I also presume that the Eastern Alliance technology is on par with the West. Apollo mentioned that the Galactica was capable of getting to Terra at light speed and he recieved a surprised response by Western officials stating that he had space vessels that were capable of attaining light speed.

Comment: This seems pretty speculative. A good answer should be based on something more concrete than impressions or presumptions. The question specifically asked if there were any official tech specs for the Destroyer.